# Word Choice -difference between "came by" or "came"?

Tags: word-choice

Yesterday I was watching a movie where I saw the use of this phrase "came by", but I felt it was easily replaceable with only "came".  Please suggest whether they are replaceable or if there are uses which  are specific.

Example: I _____ to wish you luck for your exam.

Why should it have the preposition after?

Comment: Came by, dropped by, stopped by, etc connote not staying for long and usually the visit is just a stop inside some larger trip for a different purpose.

Comment: For example, I was on my way to the post office but I wanted to come by to wish you luck ***on*** your exam.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, in my experience, using "came" implies that someone came specifically to a place, perhaps with purpose, whereas using "came by" in its place could indicate that the person is making a stop in that place among others, and that he or she might only stay a short while before resuming their excursion.

To say, "I'll come by tomorrow after work.", is a polite way to indicate to someone that you're going to visit them somewhere, but only briefly without expressly saying that you have other places to be or things to do.

Comment: Yes and that's because of the difference between 'by roads' and 'high roads' where always, 'by' means local and 'high' something much bigger, such as 'official/national/main…'

The 'high' half has little place here but the 'by' distinction still implies staying only a short while or having other places to be or things to do…